# Resampling or Basic Simulation and confidence intervals

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap, simulation, resampling

I have a population of sales that might be won or lost.  I know the rate that they are won from historical data.  This case 30% of them historically win. To figure out how much money I will be making off of these sales I need to weight them.  I could just add up all the values of the sales then take 30% of that number, but there is high variance in what the value of single sales are.

```
> describe(Dataset$V1)
      var    n     mean      sd median  trimmed   mad  min     max    range  skew
    1   1 2314 185090.7 1129744  32000 52077.27 37065 1000 3.5e+07 34999000 19.26
      kurtosis       se
    1    478.5 23485.42
    > sum(Dataset$V1)*.3
     [1] 128489970
```

So I figured that if you win 30% of them then let's try sampling the population at a win rate of 30%.  I ran the following code

```
#Put the Percentage Value you want to use here
P <- .30
X <- round(nrow(Dataset)*P)
#Figured out how many wins will be based on different sample sizes.
boot <- data.frame(
  boot = replicate(10000, sum(sample(Dataset$V1, size=X)))
)
write.csv(boot, file=ThePath, row.names=FALSE)
```

I have replacement as False because a single sale can't be won more than once. I do know that only the very first sale is picked at a 30% rate and the rest are picked at a slightly lower rate due to no replacement.

So it randomly takes 30% of the data and then adds it up because I only care about the total expected value. I have it do this 10,000 times then I turned it into a histogram to see the distribution.  Then have it set up to calculate what % of the 10,000 runs each bin has.  Then look for about 8000 or 80% of the values in sequential bins.

Can I then say that 80% of the time in a simulation of 10,000 the expected total value of the sales is expected to be within X and X?  Or should I be using a normal bootstrap confidence interval calculation? Does the fact that the original data is skewed create issues and in some of the datasets when I run this code the Bootstrapped data comes out almost bimodal, does that lead to problems also?

Comment: I would question your choice of sampling without replacement, because this is inconsistent with your assumptions and objectives. You are using the historical data as a proxy for *future* sales. Those future sales will *not* act like draws from a finite population of sales; instead--assuming the future is like the past and all sales are independent--they will act like ongoing draws *with replacement* from a fixed sales distribution.

Comment: @whuber I think the future population of *potential* sales is known, just not which will be won & which lost.

Comment: You're assuming that you'll win *exactly* 30% of the sales.  It could be better to let this proportion vary a bit.

Comment: @Scortchi you are correct the future population of potential sales is known.  Also as for exactly 30%, I thought about that but don't know how to implement that currently.  Also I rounded down the win % that were calculated so 34% became 30%. As over estimating is worse than underestimating in these cases.

Comment: @whuber The historic data is just used to figure out win rates, the future potential sales are known at each time of calculation from open bids/sales.  Due to the fact that the future potential sales are known and I am trying to figure out how much those are all "worth".  We know that only 30% of these potential sales will become real revenue.  With replacement a single potential sale can win twice, and that is not possible as once something is won it can't be won again.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, Dan. By the way, "historic" and "historical" have different meanings.  I'm pretty sure you want to use "historical," unless perhaps you believe your previous salesmanship was of such epic proportions that people will build statues and memorials to you. :-)

Comment: Do you have historical data on the %age of sales that were won in each period?  If so you could use that data to add uncertainty.  Also, I would not round down your 30% estimate but rather weight the resultant CI by the magnitude of harm of getting each outcome wrong.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Yes I have how old the sales were but the data is, iffy at best when it comes to age because of the way the system keeps the record, and also because of the current method of data entry isn't what one would call, consistent.  Things are not entered or updated in a timely manner.

Comment: Do you want to assume the size of the sale is unrelated to whether you win?

Comment: @MichaelBishop Currently that will be the case.  Later if I find differences in other items like size of the sale, I think I will have to build/learn to build a bigger/more advanced Monte Carlo simulation.